# How do you validate a phone number in Java with a do/while?

Tags: java, eclipse, phone-number

I am trying to validate a phone number using Java. How can I ensure that the string is also the correct length (10 digits).

```
do{
    System.out.println("Please provide the phone number starting with area code: ");
    this.phone = input.nextLine();
} while (!phone.matches("[0-9]"));
```

Comment: If you're going to use a regex, why not: `while (!phone.matches("\d{10}");`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: @dave generally correct, but `\d` is wrong. Should be `\\d`.

Comment: @Tom, why? "\d" is not a Java escape sequence.

Comment: @dave and that's why you need to escape the first backslash.

Comment: @dave backslash is a Java escape character in a `String`. `"\\d{10}"` is the valid one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your regular expression to match exactly 10 digits.

```
do{
    System.out.println("Please provide the phone number starting with area code: ");
    this.phone = input.nextLine();
}while (!phone.matches("[0-9]{10}"));
```

One thing: I'm not sure if this type of validation is good. What if the user enters his phone number with a leading plus sign or something like that? Whitespaces as seperator?